# Chrome Remote Desktop

Tags: remote

Has anyone found the buildable source for the Chrome Remote Desktop server?  I would love to be able to use CRD to connect to my Raspi; Right now I am using VNC (not reliable) or RDP (not secure); neither of which offer a safe way to access my Pi outside my firewall.

All of the Deb packages for CRD are for ARM64 and I would like to build my own for the Pi. hints anyone?